# How to add hyperlink to String in java6?

Tags: java, string, hyperlink

I want to add hyperlink to email text. Currently it is giving output like->

Change your access here: "https://www.google.com/".

Want to change it as->
Change your access here: [Change access](https://www.google.com/)

I am having code like this.

```
public Hashtable constructEmail() {

   Hashtable email = new Hashtable();

   StringBuffer msgTxt = new StringBuffer();
   msgTxt.append("Change your access here: ")
   msgTxt.append("www.google.com");

   email.put("body", msgTxt.toString());
   return email;
}
```

Do I need to convert this to html format?

Comment: This doesn't (entirely) depend on the string, it depends on how you render it. You should look in the code that puts that string in the body of your email and how the mail itself is generated.

Comment: For text only emails it is the email client rendering links as links and not as text. You might want to try to add the protocol (e.g. https://).

Comment: To have a hyperlink with a text that's different from the URL, you *must* send the email as HTML, and use explicit HTML anchor tags: `"<a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">Change access</a>"`.